# How to remove the extra characters in groovy script used in Jmeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

Below is the part of my JSON request. I need to paramaterize values by giving 1 ,2 or more depends on each request, but by default the request is taking extra characters though I am generating the request through Groovy.

```
[ 
  {
   "key": "Login",
   "operator": "EQUAL",
   "fieldType": "STRING",
   "values": [
              "AB1234",
              "CB6988",
              "BM9899"
             ]
   }
]
```

I tried generating the script through Groovy and pulling the data from excel sheet csv data config set.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9VgQ.png)

In Excel sheet, if I pass more than one value like above , its adding extra character in the request. How to handle this?

```
[ 
 {
  "key": "Login",
  "operator": "EQUAL",
  "fieldType": "STRING",
  "values": [
             "AB1234\",
             \"CB6988\",
             \"BM9899"
             ]
 }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

We cannot answer this question without seeing your Groovy code and knowing what "extra character" it's adding which you would like to remove. Your both JSON objects are equal (and invalid)

If you have a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) `foo` from the CSV file having the value of `AB1234,CB6988,BM9899` and want to generate the following JSON out of it:

```
[
  {
    "key": "Login",
    "operator": "EQUAL",
    "fieldType": "STRING",
    "values": [
      "AB1234",
      "CB6988",
      "BM9899"
    ]
  }
]
```

you will need to do something like:

```
vars.put('foo', 'AB1234,CB6988,BM9899')

def payload = []

payload.add([key: 'Login', operator: 'EQUAL', fieldType: 'STRING', values: vars.get('foo').split(',').collect { value -> value.trim() }])

log.info(new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(payload).toPrettyString())
```

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: import groovy.json.JsonBuilder 

def json = new JsonBuilder()
def tagsValues = vars.get("searchSpecFilters").split("\\|")
class Tag {String key; String operator; String fieldtype; String values1}

List<Tag> tagsList = new ArrayList<>();
tagsValues.each {
    String[] tag = it.split("\\:")
    tagsList.add(new Tag(key: tag[0], operator: tag[1], fieldtype: tag[2], values1:tag[3]))
}

Json
{
searchSpecFilters tagsList.collect { tag ->
        ["key"   : tag.key,
         "operator": tag.operator,
         "fieldType" : tag.fieldtype,
         "values" : [tag.values1]]
     }

Comment: The code seems to be unrelated to your current question, the CSV file doesn't have any `|` symbols and the JSON you posted doesn't match the one your code generates.  You will need to ask a new one and provide the `searchSpecFilters` variable value (can be seen using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter)), the expected JSON output and the actual JSON output

Comment: This is the values I am passing from CSV data config file, and I am giving in the same cell..."AB1234","CB6988","BM9899"                                                                                       But finally when generating the json script, it automatically comes like this in the request    "\"AB1234\",\"CB6988\",\"BM9899\"")   I am not getting why the request is getting created like this, why the escape characters is getting added..